# Linux terminal replace path with symbol

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I work with deep files and the paths shown in terminal are too long!

like: `user@user-pc ~/work/projects/development/react/experiments/lib/example/src/....`

Is there any way to replace `~/work/projects/development/react/` with react symbol for example? Or any other symbol? Or even with a word with different color?!

Comment: This should be asked over at Unix & Linux. But first see here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266256/compact-bash-prompt-when-using-a-directory-tree-filename/266264

Comment: Why only `~/work/projects/development/react/` and not the rest? can you echo your `PS1` value? `echo $PS1`? What is your exact expected requirement?

Comment: @Inian that's just an example.. I want to replace only that and it will be like: user@user-pc [ReactSymbol here]/experiments/lib/example/src/....

Comment: Maybe simply change directory to `~/work/projects/development/react/`?

Comment: Are you talking about how the displays your directory, or how to shorten a pathname to invoke a command?

Comment: @chepner I'm talking about displaying, I added aliases for navigation shortcuts, but when working with deep files,  the path looks horrible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) and there are a lot of themes which can fit for you.
This is how it could look like

[image: Oh My Zsh]

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes